# During while loops, interpret next character?

Tags: java

```
public class test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please insert a word.:  ");
        String word = (" ");
        while (in.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println(in.next().charAt(0));
        }
    }
}
```

I am attempting to read each letter from the input and seperate it with a space.

For example: Input is `Yes.`

The output should be

```
Y
E
S
.
```

I do not understand how to make the char go to the next letter in the input. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you expect the user to enter the word one character at a time, or the whole word at once?

Comment: The whole word at once.

Comment: Either of the solutions with +1 below should work - be clear whether you want newlines separating them as your output shows or spaces, as Regon tried to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a bug in 'hasNextLine' your loop -- an extraneous ; semicolon before the loop body. The semicolon (do nothing) will be looped, then the body will be executed once.

Once you fix that, you need to loop over the characters in the word. Inside the 'hasNextLine' loop:

```
String word = in.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    char ch = word.charAt(i);
    // print the character here..  followed by a newline.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    String word = in.next();
    for (char c: word.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```